# Laravel PDF data:image issue

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, base64

I have generated a pdf using *Laravel 6.x* **PDF**

And I'm trying to show a base64 image in the pdf but its not displaying.

For Example::

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

If I use the same code in any HTML file then its showing the image correctly.

**SO I'm looking for a solution to display the above image in a pdf file generated using php Laravel 6.x PDF**

Comment: No if you use the exact data image that I mentioned in the example in a HTML file then its working fine but its not showing in pdf.

Comment: I'm generating the pdf using laravel PDF

Comment: i'm having the same issue. do you have any resolutions yet? This question is not a duplicate of the answer suggested. Totally different problem

Comment: aha!!!! i got it!! publish the config file and change the `"dpi" => 96` to some higher dpi value. I changed mine to 196 and my images started appearing.

Comment: @maximus1127 Are you using the Laravel? Which config file that you are referring to?

Comment: yes, I'm using laravel with this package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

the config file can be found by running this command: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"`

then in that file, change the dpi